# Is there a name for the following reflection language feature and standard way to implement?

Tags: javascript, java, c, actionscript-3, syntax

Let's say you have an object and you want to get a string of the name of the property you are referencing. Is there a name for that? I mean it's some sort of `reflection` but is there a more specific name for it and do languages implement it in standard way?

For example, this feature exists for class based objects using `toString()` in JavaScript or ActionScript.

```
var person:Person = new Person();
var nameOfClass:String = person.toString();
trace(nameOfClass); // traces "Person" or "com.mydomain.model.Person"
```

But since properties can be null or undefined you can't use `toString()` as it will throw an error or if it's not `null` it will get the `value`:

```
var person:Person = new Person();
var nameOfProperty:String = person.name.toString(); // error is thrown when null
person.name = "John";
person.name.toString(); // traces the value "John" not the type
```

So I'm guessing some languages would have a global function like so.

```
var person:Person = new Person();
var nameOfProperty:String = propertyName(person.name);

trace(nameOfProperty); // traces "name"

nameOfProperty = propertyName(person.zipCode);
trace(person.zipCode); // traces "zipCode"
```

Is there a specific name for this feature and if so how is implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and no, there's no standard, nor can there be.

Every language implements types differently (and many don't even retain them through to run time). In C++, classes aren't aware of their namespace. In JS, prototypical inheritance makes the whole thing meaningless (although you can fetch the constructor, which has a name of its own).

When accessing the properties within an instance, it gets even uglier. The property might be a getter/setter and link to a child object or a field with a totally different name.

Plenty of languages do provide runtime type information at the class level, but I'm unaware of a language with heavy enough properties that they can reflect themselves out of the class. Each property knowing where it's assigned on a parent would probably be impossible, since an object may be assigned to multiple variables. Querying that would give you an array of outstanding references back, but creating that list would introduce more references (albeit weak).

In certain languages, especially ones that implement garbage collection in regular old code rather than the underlying (virtual) machine, you *may* be able to look up all smart pointers that are holding an object. This is typically an implementation detail of the smart pointer class, so it knows either how many or exactly where the references live.

None of those features will help you with properties, though. I think that's mostly because you can assign them anywhere, so it's not very meaningful. If you want named properties, use a `Map`. ;)